# table reload not working from textFieldShouldEndEditing delegate method

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

I am using **custom cell**   and I have a **textField in my customer 
cell**.

When I complete editing textfeild, it's delegate method 
**textFieldShouldEndEditing** getting called and am reloading the table 
view which exist in the another class. the problem is tableview delegate
 not working(tableview reload).

```
**//Custom cell class textfield delegate method**
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
**//tableReload is existing class table view reload method**
       [rptCartdelegate tableReload];
       return YES;

}
```

**//another class method**

```
-(void)tableReload{
     //here table is not nill have object information and passing array also not empty
    [tableview reload];

}
```

I think I explained my problem.. 
If you have any ideas please share your ideas ...I hope your ideas will 
help me..
thanks.

Comment: Immediately before the `reloadData` call, put `NSLog(@"%@", tableView);` to make sure that your pointer to the tableView is not nil

Comment: I check out.. tableview not nil, it has object value like this.. receiptTableView=<UITableView: 0xa004c00; frame = (-3 533; 787 345); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x935b750>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>. Delegate: ReceiptEntryViewController, DataSource: ReceiptEntryViewController

Comment: As Garret says. put NSLog in  textfiledshould return method to ensure that it calls

Comment: Did you Set the delegate for your textField . Check out , Whether it has being called or not ...?

Comment: Hi all I check out ..while key board return calling textFieldShouldEndEditing: method and from there another class method  *tableReload* also calling finally [tableview reload] also calling but no change on UI.

Comment: I think . I am calling the tableview delegates before finishing the textFeild delegates. Is it work like this?

Comment: are you performing changes to the dataSource of your tableView?

Comment: Yes. I have changed my dataSource...

Comment: After finished TextFeildShouldendediting deletege method ,when I manually  swiping tableview, it's getting changing the UI(reloading the tableview).

Comment: just in case: you are aware, that it should be `[tableview reloadData]` instead of `[tableview reload]`?

Comment: Sorry .. I am using [tableview reloadData] only...

Answer (score 2):

Just change the method **textFieldShouldEndEditing:**  to **textFieldDidEndEditing:**

Comment: I've had the same problem and **this answer solved it** for me. I wasn't able to find any documentation of the observed behavior but it seems that UITableView.reloadData() just has no effect when called from within UITableViewDelegate.textFieldShouldEndEditing().